# Marginal effect in logistic regression greater than 1

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, marginal-effect

I have a logistic regression and I calculated the marginal effects. Now I have a value for a numeric variable greater than 1, it's even greater than 2. I'm sorry that I can't give you a reproducable example because the data is private.
I used the function `margins` of the package with the same name.
I thought you can interpret the coefficient like this: If x increases by 1 then y increases by the marginal effect coefficient c.p.. y is a probability in the case of a logistic regression. Then I would argue that the coefficient has to be in [-1, 1]. 
Did I get anything wrong? If yes how do I interpret the coefficient? If no, what could have happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have to do with the scale of the predictor. If the values the predictor can take are low (e.g., between 0 and 1), then a moderate-sized effect will appear to be large. For example, consider the following scenario. An aptitude test is scored from 0 to 100. You want to know the marginal effect of test score on the probability of getting a job. You find that the marginal effect is .02, which indicates that for each additional point on the test, the probability of getting the job increases by .02 on average.

But now let's say you changed the scale of the variable so that it corresponds to the proportion of items correct (i.e., you divide the test score by 100). Now, a 1-unit increase in test score means going from getting 0% to getting 100% on the test, a huge change. The computed average marginal effect will be 100 times the marginal effect on the scale of the raw test scores, so the marginal effect will be 100*.02 = 2.

See if this is the case with your data. If you want a more interpretable value, try multiplying your focal predictor by a larger number that makes substantive sense. For example, if your variable was "decades", multiply by 10 to get the effect in years. If your variable was 1000s of dollars, try multiplying by 100 to get the effect in $100,000. Doing so may improve the interpretability of your model and will not change the statistical properties of the estimate.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense, great explanation!