# Average Marginal Effect interpretation for probit Model

Tags: regression, probit, marginal-effect

I'd like to have your feedback about the interpretation of the Average Marginal Effect (AME) for a probit model. Suppose we have the following model
\begin{equation}
P(y=1|x)= \Phi(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 \text{ln}(x_2))
\end{equation}
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal.
To compute the marginal effect of $x_1$ on the probability that $y$ takes value one:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P(y=1|x)}{\partial x_1} = \phi(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_1 + \hat{\beta}_2 \text{ln}(x_2)) \hat{\beta}_1
\end{equation}

For a discrete change in $\Delta x_1=1$, the marginal effect reads
\begin{equation}
\Delta P(y=1|x) = \phi(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_1 + \hat{\beta}_2 \text{ln}(x_2)) \hat{\beta}_1 
\end{equation}
The AME is obtained by computing the
effect for each observation, using their specific x-values, and then reporting the sample mean of the effects.

If the AME for $x_1$ is equal to 0.09, this means that, if $x_1$ increases by one unit, the probability that $y=1$ is 0.09 higher. Is that correct?

If $x_1$ denotes a growth rate, say $x_1=g_x$, and the AME for $x_1$ is now 3.5, this means that a for 1% increase in $x_1$, the probability that $y=1$ takes on value 1 is 0.035 higher. Is that correct?

Now, for $x_2$, the marginal effect on the probability that $y$ takes value one is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P(y=1|x)}{\partial x_2} = \phi(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_1 + \hat{\beta}_2 \text{ln}(x_2)) \frac{\hat{\beta}_2}{x_2}
\end{equation}
Replacing $\partial$ with $\Delta$ and multiplying the left and the right by $\Delta x_2 \times 100$
\begin{equation}
 \Delta P(y=1|x) = \frac{\phi(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_1 + \hat{\beta}_2 \text{ln}(x_2))}{100} \hat{\beta}_2  \% \Delta x_2
\end{equation}
where $\% \Delta x_2 \equiv \frac{\Delta x_2}{x_2}100$ is the percentage increase in $x_2$.
If the AME for $x_2$ is equal to 0.4, this means that if $x_2$ doubles, the probability that $y=1$ is 0.4 higher, and if $x_2$ increases by $10\%$, the probability that $y=1$ is 0.04 higher (I don't think so, it should correspond to the increase in probability if $x_2$ increases by 172%). What's the correct interpretation? I have doubts on this point because in the linear level-log model, that's would be an approximation working only for small $\% \Delta x_2$

Comment: I am not sure how you could get an AME greater than one. I would also encourage you to calculate finite differences for discrete variables rather than derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, from real data I got an AME >1 in R by using the function avg_slopes. Maybe this has happened because of the scale of my regressors. Indeed, the AME > 1 occur for regressors that are average deviations from the trend. Is that a problem? Are the interpretations listed above correct?

Comment: Your expression for the discrete change is incorrect; you just wrote the expression for the AME again. The discrete change depends on the levels of $x_1$ and should be a difference between two probabilities. It's certainly possible for AMEs for probabilities to be larger than 1; see my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/457732/116195) about how to interpret that.

Comment: @Noah thanks for your comment, I've just upvoted the answer at the link you provided. Indeed, $x_1$ denotes an average growth rate during a given time period and it takes values in the interval [-0.05,0.07]. An AME=3.5 for $x_1$ means that if the growth rate doubles, the increase in probability will be 2 (which of course is not possible). Maybe, I could multiply $x_1$ by $100$ to make the AME more interpretable.  Can I claim that a 1% increase in the growth rate makes the probability increasing by 0.035? In your opinion, does it make sense having a growth rate as predictor?